# Loading effect on asp.net postback

Tags: asp.net

I having hard time implementing a YouTube Loading Effect in my asp.net page,

Im using the effect from here https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/09/18/creative-loading-effects/

the effects just works perfect when I use it with Button Element, but when I try to implement it on Linkbutton, it does not work,

Can anyone help me with it, or if you have another suggestion for adding loading effect on Postback in modern and neat way just like the one provided in the above site, please provide me with full code (im pretty newbie)

Im using the linkbutton to load data from database to repeater

Thanks :)

Comment: kindly provide your code to modify it for you to work in all cases. Link Button is different because its rendered as an anchor.

Comment: can you share the code?